# How do you show an animation behind a text mask in CSS?

Tags: css, animation

I recently came across a cool effect where the developer displayed an animation that was masked with text in CSS. You can find it on the headline of this page here: https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/features/whats-new.html

How do you achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out after a little of investigation it is actually quite simple:

You just put an SVG animation into your surrounding container as a background, and then use {mix-blend-mode: lighten;} together with {background: white} on the text:

```
.container {
  background: url(https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/cc/us/en/products/xd/features/knockout_animation.svg);

}

.container h1 {
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  background: white;
  
}
```